# Excel VBA fufilling template with additional rows

Tags: vba, excel

Maybe could someone know, how to perform such actions in VBA:
I have an template on one sheet and table on second. 
Table looks like:

```
Unit    Project Project Name   Task Number   Invoice    Sum of Amount
304     136950  Name1               02.3    invoice1    156.45
304     136955  Name2               01.6    invoice1    22.35
```

So when I'm filling template, I need to check, if the unit naming is the same, and if Yes, then additional line should be created in template.

Currently, I have a macro, which fulfills template only for one line separately, and the problem for me is that if I'm creating a check, still because of "For Each... " I'm facing with problem with new sheet creation instead of line.

As I'm quite new in VBA, is there a possibility to help me with the issue, so that for example, if Unit is same on 1+ lines (the order set by unit, so there won't be situation that unit is repeated after several lines lower), instead of creating new sheet with filled template, new row in template would be created?

Macro I have now:

```
  Set myRange = Range(Sheets("Data").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Data").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))

i = 1

For Each r In myRange.Cells


Sheets("template").Select
Sheets("template").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Sheets("template (2)").Select
Sheets("template (2)").Name = "Invoice " & i
Range("C1:D1").Select



ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:="{Unit}", Replacement:=r.Offset(0, 0), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False


ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:="{pr number}", Replacement:=r.Offset(0, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:="{pr name}", Replacement:=r.Offset(0, 2), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False


 ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:="{task nr}", Replacement:=r.Offset(0, 3), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

 ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:="{invoice number}", Replacement:=r.Offset(0, 4), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:="{amount}", Replacement:=r.Offset(0, 5), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

i = i + 1

   Next r
```

Ranges which should be copied as new lines, are stored here:

```
Range("A24:H29").Select 'templated data, which should be copied if new row needed and then here I'm fulfilling info from table
Selection.Copy
Range("A31").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = j + 1 'line number
Range("A33").Select
```

Comment: You want to fill the template sheet with unique *Unit* values (one row in template sheet equals one unique *Unit* in the table) ? So for example there are 10x Unit `304`, 3x Unit `308` and 20x Unit `401`, the template would have 1 row for each `304` `308` `401` ? Is this the issue?

Comment: Hi, Yes, exactly, so data for template is moving to new sheet and for each unique Unit I need to add additional rows in template with fulfilled data from table above

Comment: So as from your example, it would be 10 rows in 304, next template 3x308 etc.

Comment: Aha, so the *Template* sheet is more like a summary for each *Unit*, with all records for this *Unit*. There will be one *Template* sheet for each *Unit*. Correct? We are getting real close.

Comment: Yes, I have one sheet called template (pre-defined),where I have all those {Unit}, {project nr} defined already, so I need only to fulfill it accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Any news about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `For Loop`. Store one unique unit name (e.g. *304*), then compare subsequent rows if they match. After you find a mismatch, you know that one row above mismatch, the range for stored unique ends. Than copy that range to newly created sheet.

```
Sub CreateNewTemplates()
    Dim wsTable As Worksheet
    Dim wsNewTemplate As Worksheet
    Dim rngStoredUnique As Range

    Set wsTable = Worksheets("Table") 'worksheet where all the data is
    With wsTable
        For x = 1 To 50 'adjust to your needs
            Set rngStoredUnique = .Cells(x, 1) 'adjust to your needs
            Sheets("template").Copy after:=Sheets("template") 'adjust to your needs
            Set wsNewTemplate = ActiveSheet
            wsNewTemplate.Name = "Invoice " & rngStoredUnique.Value 'adjust to your needs
            For y = 1 To 50 - x 'adjust to your needs
                If rngStoredUnique <> rngStoredUnique.Offset(y, 0) Then 'check if the unit below is different than stored
                    Set rngToCopy = .Range(rngStoredUnique, rngStoredUnique.Offset(y - 1, 0)).Resize(ColumnSize:=10) 'adjust to your needs
                    x = x + y - 1
                    rngToCopy.Copy Destination:=wsNewTemplate.Cells(1, 1) 'adjust to your needs
                    If rngStoredUnique.Offset(y, 0) = "" Then Exit Sub
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next y
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```